# Fast k-NN search over bag-of-words models

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, knn, kdtree

I have a large amount of documents of equal size. For each of those documents I'm building a bag of words model (BOW). Number of possible words in all documents is limited and large (2^16 for example). Generally speaking, I have N histograms of size K, where N is a number of documents and K is histogram width. I can calculate distance between any two histograms.

**First optimization opportunity.** Documents usually uses only small subset of words (usually less then 5%, most of them less then 0.5%).

**Second optimization opportunity** Subset of used words is varying from document to document much so I can use bits instead of word counts.

#### Query by content

Query is a document as well. I need to find `k` most similar documents.

#### Naive approach

- Calculate BOW model from query.
- For each document in dataset:

  - Calculate it's BOW model.
  - Find distance between query and document.

Obviously, some data structure should be used to track top-ranked documents (priority queue for example).

I need some sort of index to get rid of full database scan. KD-tree comes to mind but dimensionality and size of the dataset is very high. One can suggest to use some subset of possible words as features but I don't have separate training phase and can't extract this features beforehand.

I've thought about using MinHash algorithm to prune search space but I can't design an appropriate hash functions for this task.

Answer (score 1):

k-d-tree and similar indexes are for *dense* and continuous data.

Your data most likely is sparse.

A good index for finding the nearest neighbors on sparse data is inverted lists. Essentially the same way search engines like Google work.